# 質問者本人によるものかを確認出来ない情報の追記、削除を伴う編集提案を承認するべきか？

Tags: 討議, レビュー

以下の質問では、同名の異なるアカウントから追加情報の編集提案がありました。そしてこれは[承認されています](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/26701)。

- [unityをやるのに必要なファイル等をポータブルに持ち歩きたい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/67861/32986)

編集提案のレビュー時に、上記のような場面に遭遇することは少なくないのですが、今回のような

1. 元の質問者と編集提案者が同一人物であるかが不明であり、
2. 編集提案では質問文の整形などだけではなく、情報の追加もされている

といった状況で、編集提案を承認するべきでしょうか？また、これらの 2 つのアカウントの所有者が同一人物であることを確認する方法がありますか？

このような編集提案を承認してしまうと、同名のアカウントさえ作成すれば、第三者が編集提案を通して任意の変更を、質問者のように振舞いながら行えるのではないかと感じています。

Answer (score 14):

些細なフォーマットの修正提案などの場合を除いて、情報の追加や削除を伴う編集提案はたとえ表示されるユーザ名が同じであっても、同一人物であるか確認ができるまで **承認すべきではない**、と個人的には考えます。
(本人であるなら信用度によらず編集できるはずなので、まずコメントで本人か確認すべき)

また、2つのアカウントが同一人物であるかについてはモデレーター権限である程度の詳しい情報(メールアドレスやIPアドレス)を確認することができますが、これらも確定情報ではないのでまずはコメント等で確認を取る、というスタンスでいます。

Answer (score 1):

編集はもっと気軽に行って良いと考えます。変更は全部トラッキングされているので問題があればその時点でロールバックするなり再編集すれば良いです。

編集が妥当かどうかを判断するのに本人の編集かどうか、というものを考慮するのはすごい手間が増えることですし、モデレータの数が限られているならそれは妥当だと思いますが、それなりの人間が参加しているわけなので、ある時点で不適切な編集が承認されたとしてもじきに適切な状態に戻ると思います。

むしろ、編集のハードルを上げて頻繁な編集が行われなくなる方がデメリットかなと思います。

Comment: 編集はいつでも自由に行う事ができますが、基本は [元投稿の意味を変更しない](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) が守られている必要があり、このルールを徹底するために、まだ信用度が低い間は他ユーザーのレビューを受ける仕組みになっています。 / [コミュニティ Wiki](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki) ではない通常の投稿は、投稿者本人の意思や意図を尊重する必要があると思います。

Comment: 編集提案のレビューにて、却下理由の一つとして「元投稿の意図が失われています。大きな変更をする場合でも、投稿者の意図を保つべきです。」が用意されています。

Comment: 「元投稿の意味を変更しない」を尊重すべきというのは同意です。ただそれは「本人の編集かどうか」は独立していていいと思います。
挙げられている例でいうと意味は変わっていない（情報の追加はあるけれども質問の意味は変わっていない（『Unityを使うために必要なものをUSBフラッシュドライブに入れているが毎回初期化されているような動きをする』という大意）というのは客観的に同意できると思います。）ので別に問題ないと考えます。
つまり、（このケースにおいてもそうでなくても）「本人の編集かどうか」は参考情報にすぎないと考えてよくて、ほとんどの人はそれを判断するすべを持ってないし、本人でなかったとしても質問の意味を大きく変えてないのであれば編集を承認するのは問題ないと思います。

Comment: 元の投稿の意味を変更しないのであれば誰による編集かは関係ない、という部分には同意です。一方でこの質問では「情報の追加もされている」という部分が鍵だと思っていて、この部分が元の投稿の意味を変更しているのではないかと考えています。

Comment: そういうことならあとはスタンスの違い（個人差がある）だと思います。私は編集を保守的にしすぎない方が良いと考えているので、今回の例では情報の追加はありますが、それによって回答が変わるほどのものではないと思うので、この編集が承認されることに異議はありません。一方でもっと保守的であることが望ましい、という意見があることもまた当然だと思います。

Answer (score 1):

状況と内容を見るに同一人物っぽいと考えるので、同じ状況であれば承認します。表示名が違うとか編集の内容次第では別の判断をするかもしれませんが。

厳密に言えば「第三者が勝手に想像した状況を質問者を装って追記した」という可能性も考えられなくもありませんが、無視してもいい程度のリスクだと思います。

そのために一律にrejectして「アカウントを統合してから出直してこい」というのは不親切かなと思います。

この件について言えば、同一人物と考えてもよいかどうか、が問題であって、質問の意図を変更する編集かどうか、は本質ではないでしょう。